# Indian passport: Travel to Australia from the United States

Tags: usa, australia

I am an Indian passport holder and currently in the US on my F1 student visa. I am planning to travel to Australia in December. My sister will be sponsoring me for my visa to Australia. If granted a visa, can I travel to Australia from the US? Or will I have to go to India and then go to Australia? Also while returning, can I return to the US from Australia?

Answer (score 1):

If you are granted an Australian visa, you can travel to Australia from any country.  The airline will check your visa details electronically (using the Advance Passenger Processing system) at check-in, before allowing you to board your flight to Australia.

When you leave Australia, there are no restrictions on your visa in terms of where you travel.  However, the airline will check that you have a right to enter your destination country (in this case, check that you have a US visa) before allowing you to board your flight out of Australia.